# Links from email newsletters not working

Tags: bug, email, newsletter

Trying to click on links in a newsletter email is giving me an error:

> This site can’t be reached
>   sg-links.stackoverflow.email’s server IP address could not be found.
>   Search Google for links stack overflow
>   email click ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

I checked on Down For Everyone Or Just For Me, and it appears that it's not just an issue with my connection/DNS: https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/sg-links.stackoverflow.email

**Update**: Seems to be working now. Maybe just a DNS thing working its way through the internet?

Comment: Well, http://stackoverflow.email works for me, though probably they do have some DNS issue according to that error.

Comment: Try running `tracert stackoverflow.email` from windows command line, it might help the team debug the issue. (Or reveal it's specific to you, e.g. ISP blocking it.)

Comment: Well they seem to be working now. Maybe just a DNS thing working its way through the internet

Comment: Yeah, most likely. Probably better to leave this here for a while, see if this happens again or to other people.